# Como recorrer array de objetos Angular

Tags: javascript, array, angular, objeto, filtro

un placer saludarles, necesito la ayuda de alguien porfavor:

Resulta que tengo un objeto y dentro de el se encuentra un array de objetos ¿Cómo debo de recorrerlo?

El objeto es algo así:

```
     {
        "afiliado": 
        { 
            "attentionSchedules": [
                {
                "room": "x",
                "floor": 2,
                "schedules": [
                {
                "days": [
                "MO",
                "TU",
                "FR",
                "TH",
                "WE"
                ],
                "_id": "xxxxx",
                "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
                "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
                "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
                "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
                }
                ], 
                room: {[]}
]
            }
}
```

Quiero acceder a initialTimeStr y finalTimeStr ¿Como puedo recorrer este objeto y filtrar estos datos en angular?

Ya logre mapear el arreglo:

[image: Arreglo de objeto]

Lo hice con:

```
console.log('hour :>>', this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules ))
```

Pero no se cómo extraer "initialTimeStr" y "finalTimeStr" ¿alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: console.log(Object.values(object1).map(es=>es.attentionSchedules[0].schedules[0]. initialTimeStr ))..>//[ '07:00 am' ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De manera manual, puedes hacer esto.

```js
let objeto = {
  "afiliado": {
    "attentionSchedules": [{
      "room": "x",
      "floor": 2,
      "schedules": [{
        "days": [
          "MO",
          "TU",
          "FR",
          "TH",
          "WE"
        ],
        "_id": "xxxxx",
        "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
        "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
        "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
        "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
      }],
      "room": {}
    }
    ]
  }
}


let initial = objeto.afiliado.attentionSchedules[0].schedules[0].initialTime
let final = objeto.afiliado.attentionSchedules[0].schedules[0].finalTime

console.log({initial, final})
```

Lo puedes automatizar con `forEach`:

```js
let objeto = {
  "afiliado": {
    "attentionSchedules": [{
      "room": "x",
      "floor": 2,
      "schedules": [{
        "days": [
          "MO",
          "TU",
          "FR",
          "TH",
          "WE"
        ],
        "_id": "xxxxx",
        "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
        "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
        "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
        "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
      }],
      "room": {}
    }]
  }
}


objeto.afiliado.attentionSchedules.forEach(attentionSchedule => {

  attentionSchedule.schedules.forEach(schedule => {
    console.log(schedule.initialTime)
    console.log(schedule.finalTime)

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que tengas esa respuesta guardada en algún arreglo tipo

```
schedules:any [] = [];
```

antes que nada te sugiero para evitar el uso del any, y usar un tipado correcto de tu respuesta, en caso de no saber el tipado que es, puedes copiar la respuesta en esta url: https://app.quicktype.io/ y luego crear un fichero interface así por ejemplo: `schedule.interface.ts` con el tipado obtenido en el sitio.

Luego tu arreglo quedaría así `schedules:Schedule[] =[]`

ya pudieras obtener perfectamente tus registros

ejemplo de una lista en tu hmtl:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let schedule for schedules">entrada: {{schedule.initialTimeStr}} - salida: {{schedule.finalTimeStr}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola! Aunque ya paso vario tiempo, gracias por responder, aprovechar para decir que por ti conoci quicktype, buenisisma herramienta, hoy la uso casi siempre

Comment: Fue un placer, estamos para ayudarnos.

Answer (score 1):

Desestructuracion
[Teoria para Desestructurar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let objeto = {
  "afiliado": {
    "attentionSchedules": [{
      "room": "x",
      "floor": 2,
      "schedules": [
        {
        "days": [
          "MO",
          "TU",
          "FR",
          "TH",
          "WE"
        ],
        "_id": "xxxxx",
        "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
        "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
        "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
        "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
      "room": {}
    }]
  }
}
const {
  afiliado: {
    attentionSchedules: [{
      room,
      floor,
     schedules: [
        {
        days,
        _id,
        //initialTimeStr ,
       // finalTimeStr,
       //initialTime,
       // finalTime
      }
    ],
      room: {}
    }]
  }
}
=objeto
  

console.log(_id);
//xxxxx
console.log(days);
//[ 'MO', 'TU', 'FR', 'TH', 'WE' ]
function printObjectDemand({
  afiliado: {
    attentionSchedules: [{
      room,
      floor,
     schedules: [
        {
        days,
        _id,
        }
    ],
      room: {}
    }]
  }
}
        ) {
  console.log(`_id: ${_id}. days: ${days}.floor:${floor} `)
}
printObjectDemand(objeto)
/*
xxxxx
[ 'MO', 'TU', 'FR', 'TH', 'WE' ]
_id: xxxxx. days: MO,TU,FR,TH,WE.floor:2 

*/
```

Comment: ¡Aqui esta! Sii, ya habia votado, esta pregunta fue de las primeras que hice y aún no tenia la reputación para comentar o dejar una respuesta fijada. Ahora, de todo los temas el que más me cuesta aún comprender es la forma correcta de recorrer el objeto, más aún cuando tiene un mayor grado de profundidad. Este problema lo resolví usando forEach, para sacar el índice y luego ya solo lo pase en un evento click. Gracias por siempre responderme!

Comment: con desestructuracion no tenes necesidad de recorrelo hay objetos muy complejos y se hace complejo con forEach  con desestructuracion podes crear  una o varias  variables que tenga cualquier valor del objeto  mira este apunte https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-object-destructuring-spread-operator-rest-parameter/.......igual te lo decia porque no habia vista que seleccionaras ninguna respuesta no por la mia en particular saludos